# Attendance Confirmation Page

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, receipt, confirmation-email

I am creating a page where students log in their attendance for a class by putting in their SID and a key provided by the professor. Then it will go through the servlet and post that the student was there on a google spreadsheet (backend). My question is, after the SID is confirmed and everything how can i redirect them to a "Thank you for your Submission" page? We want them to get a confirmation page, so that they can have a receipt to show the professor that they were in class. We would like to later implement it where we can even send a email confirmation page to the student.

```
<body>
    <div id="title">
            <h2>CSC 131 Student Attendance</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="login">
        <form action ="QuickServlet" method="post">
            <h2>Student:</h2>
            <center><input type="text" id="key" placeholder="Enter Key:"/></center>
            <center><input type="text" id="Studentid" placeholder="Enter StudentID:"/></center>
            <center><input type="submit" id="mySubmit" value="Submit"/></center>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What language are you using on your web server?

Comment: i am using Javascript with Eclipse

Comment: Javascript is a client-side language. Eclipse is a code editor. Wayne was asking what language you're using on your _server_. This is usually PHP, but could be anything (Python and Ruby are common alternatives).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is here to help with code your wrote but SO is not here to write code for you. On top of that, your HTML is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you can use `window.location.assign('confirmation-page-url');` to redirect to a new page.